# Accessing a nested property within the ConvertTo-Html cmdlet

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, azure-resource-manager

How could I add the value `Sku.Name` and `Sku.Tier` in the following html table?

```
$resourceGroupName = "(my resourcegroup name)"
$storageAccounts = Get-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$storageAccounts `
 | ConvertTo-Html `
   -property ResourceGroupName, StorageAccountName, Sku, Sku.Name, Sku.Tier, Kind, Encryption, AccessTier `
   -body "<h2>List of Storage Accounts</h2>" `
   -As List `
 | Set-Content "temp.html"
```

#### Result "temp.html"

```
List of Storage Accounts
ResourceGroupName:  "(my resourcegroup name)"
StorageAccountName: "(my storage account name)"
Sku:    Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Sku
Kind:   BlobStorage
Encryption: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Encryption
AccessTier: Cool
```

#### Expected

```
List of Storage Accounts
ResourceGroupName:  "(my resourcegroup name)"
StorageAccountName: "(my storage account name)"
Sku:    Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Sku
Sku.Name:   StandardLRS
Sku.Tier:   Standard
Kind:   BlobStorage
Encryption: Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Models.Encryption
AccessTier: Cool
```

#### Error

Trying

```
-property (Sku).Name
```

resulted:

```
+    -property (Sku).Name
+               ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Sku:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **calculated properties**:

```
-property ResourceGroupName, StorageAccountName, Sku, @{l='Sku Name'; e={$_.Sku.Name}},  @{l='Sku Tier'; e={$_.Sku.Tier}}, Kind, Encryption, AccessTier
```